# No module named 'geetools.ui' when importing from ipygee on google colab

Tags: python, geemap

I am trying to import all from ipygee with the command  `from ipygee import *` when I try to comment it I get `NotImplementedError: geetools will mostly focus on server-side methods now`  from this

```
bots_ndvi = chart.Image.series(**{'imageCollection': scaled_ndvi,
                               'region': roi,
                               'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
                               'scale': 1000,
                               'xProperty': 'system:time_start'})
bots_ndvi.renderWidget(width='50%')
```

Please assist with this, i am preparing for workshop